# forward proxy with URL rewrite

Tags: proxy, rewrite

Apologies if this is a newbie question -- I can't believe its hard, so I must be missing something.

I have an application at `https://example.com/application/*` .
It makes use of PNGs sourced from `https://reference.com/maps/*`

What I want is under the covers, a call to `https://example.com/maps/*` to return the corresponding PNG from reference.com, and also incidentally cache the content if possible.

I tried reverse proxy:

```
ProxyPass /maps/ https://reference.com/maps/
```

Now, if in my source files I have `<img src="/maps/PNG1.png">` the browser does show me `https://reference.com/maps.PNG1.png`, but it is the browser doing the fetching, not the server.

I tried forward proxy using the example at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase    "/maps/"
RewriteRule    "^(.*)$"  "https://reference.com/maps/$1"  [P]
ProxyPassReverse "/maps/" "https://example.com/maps/"
```

What the rewrite logs show is

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /maps/PNG1.png
(1) pass through /maps/PNG1.png
```

What am I missing?  There are complications -- this is all SSL (yes, SSLProxy turned on) and the call over the the PNG server uses client authentication, but I don't think this is relevant.  Oh, and its using the IBM HTTP Server, but I think the directive structure is the same as Apache.

Clue, anyone?